# How do you enabled Limited Refs in TFS Git?

Tags: git, tfs

In their articles about Git at scale, Microsoft mention [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/limited-refs) blog post which talks about a concept called "Limited Refs".  It appears to be an extremely useful feature for limiting which server branches are visible to each user to allow a more organized client experience in a non-fork based TFS Git server configuration.

Unfortunately, the article neglected to mention how to use said feature and no other information I can find online seems to document it.  I've done a bunch of digging on my own and discovered the prc_UpdateGitLimitedRefCriteria stored procedure in the TFS SQL DB that adds records to a table to apply filters to the refs returned to a client, however adding information to that table is not sufficient by itself.  There must be some on/off switch which I've been unable to locate.

Has anyone had any luck getting the Limited Refs functionality to be enabled and if so, how do you do it?

Comment: If the only reference you've found is a blog post, it's entirely possible it's an internal feature that's not intended to be used by the general public at the moment.

Comment: @DanielMann - yeah, it's possible, however everything else mentioned in the series is released and they go in to details about it's usage with verbiage that makes it sound like "you" can do it.  It may just be badly written or it may just be badly documented.  There's a TON of stuff in TFS, particularly at the lower levels, that is simply horribly documented or completely undocumented.  (Like most work with the plugins folder and even significant chunks of the REST API.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some extensive poking around the DB, I have managed to hack together a solution.  I couldn't find a way to do it through the UI, but there are two key things that have to be done in the DB to make it work.

First, you need to enable the feature, which is enabled in the repository settings.  While I couldn't find a setting in the UI, if you adjust anything from the default settings on the repo, a JSON object is saved to the dbo.tbl_PolicyConfigurationRevision table which includes an "optimizedByDefault" element which will be null, change it from null to true and the feature will now be enabled on the repo in question.

Alternately, this can be accomplished using the Policy Configuration endpoint for the TFS Rest API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).  It's a bit more involved and still involves tweaking the JSON, but it goes through officially exposed channels without requiring direct DB manipulation and will properly version the configuration change.

Second, you need to specify what the "important" refs are.  There is a stored proc and a custom data type to help with this.  dbo.prc_UpdateGitLimitedRefCriteria takes the partitionId, dataspaceId, repositoryId and two custom table data type records for the exactRefs matches and the namespaceRefs matches.  Build up the tables with your important refs in them and call the stored proc to add them to the list.

It appears that this ends up going through the prc_QueryGitRefs stored proc for filtering the refs, so you can look in there if you need more detail about how to format them so that processing works correctly.

After a bit more experimentation, it appears that there is an undocumented API endpoint for limitedRefCriteria as well that supports getting and updating ref criteria.

```
 /tfs/*collectionName*/_apis/git/repositories/*repositoryId*/limitedRefCriteria
```

Interestingly, once I knew the "optimized" keyword, it looks like using _optimized in the repo name where the article describes using _full will also work to reverse the feature. Ex:

```
https://.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/_optimized/Repo
```

If you don't have the feature on by default but use the _optimized path, it will return the filtered branches.  This might also be a safer path for those that don't want to mess with tweaking the settings json and only want to add records via stored proc to the limited refs criteria.

Comment: Just adding "\_optimized" to the clone address filtered out all branches except _master_ and my own branches. _master_ is our only protected branch though, so I don't know if all protected branches would be visible if we had multiple.

Comment: That's when you use the stored procedure to add more important branches.  It uses them in a like statement and takes care of doing escaping and adding the % on namespace matches, which are really just wildcard matches to the start.  The stored procedure is safer than the json because it's going through a maintained stored procedure that will do things in the expected way.

Comment: @keremispirli: the other set of branches you "automatically" get are your favorites.

Comment: @AJHenderson: would it make sense to provide a summary of those ref structure and/or escaping rules, for those of us that don't have an on-premise TFS instance with the stored proc source to look at?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth noting in a separate answer that **this stuff works in Azure DevOps** (hosted service).

If your clone URL is `https://dev.azure.com/*orgname*/*projectname*/_git/*reponame*`, then by inserting `_optimized/` before the repo name (as in `https://dev.azure.com/*orgname*/*projectname*/_git/_optimized/*reponame*`), you get the "filtered refs" behavior that the article talks about.

(for SSH URLs it's the same idea, add `_optimized/` right before the repo name near the end of the URL)

Furthermore, you can run GET and PUT on the `limitedRefCriteria` endpoint, for example  with fetch requests in your browser session, to provide global visibility to additional branches besides the default, the user's own branches and the user's 'favorite' branches and namespaces:

**List the repo's `limitedRefCriteria`**:

`fetch("https://dev.azure.com/*orgname*/_apis/git/repositories/*repoid*/limitedRefCriteria", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"application/json","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},"method":"GET"}).then(r => {return r.json()}).then(d => console.log(d));`

**Set the repo's `limitedRefCriteria`**:

`fetch("https://dev.azure.com/*orgname*/_apis/git/repositories/*repoid*/limitedRefCriteria", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"application/json;api-version=6.0-preview.1;","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",'Content-Type': 'application/json'},"method":"PUT",body:JSON.stringify({refExactMatches:['refs/heads/some-specific-branch'], refNamespaces:['refs/heads/some-branch-prefix/']})}).then(r => {return r.json()}).then(d => console.log(d));`

(unfortunately I found this by trial and error on the basis of the answer above, rather than any documentation available online, so I have to assume this is not officially supported...?)